# Creating a queue in Arduino?

Tags: programming

Does anyone know if there is a way to create a queue of some sort for arduino?

My project consists of simulating multiple traffic lights with crossing pedestrians on an Arduino breadboard. Since I need to assume the situation where on all sides are cars waiting + pedestrians having pressed the button, I needed to figure out a way to store these inputs into an array of some sort.

However, the problem with array I believe is that it doesn't allow me to shift the data to the left, so that the next one will be selected in the queue. Deleting the data inside an array would only merely make it null, which doesn't work.

Greatly appreciated if someone can help me by pointing to the right direction.

Comment: This is a pure programming question: the answers would be no different if you were running the same code on a PC instead of an Arduino. You need to ask this on stackoverflow.com. (Well, actually you need to search there for the no doubt many existing questions asking things similar to this. :-))

Comment: Oh, so things purely related to Arduino should be posted here, while anything related to coding itself should be done in stackoverflow. Alright, i guess I finally know how this works, time to re-post this in the right place. :)

Comment: you can't shift array to left but you can move your pointer to right it will work similarly. for eg. your array array=[1,2,3,4,5,\0], you can denote any array element by array[i] and you can increment value of i by i++.

Comment: Actually, coding related specifically to the Arduino (e.g., "I have a problem when using this Arduino library") should be posted here. But what you've described is a generic programming problem. A good rule of thumb is to think, "would this application work just as well on a PC as on an Arduino, and the code I'm asking about be unchanged or almost unchanged?"

Comment: Hmm, I guess it then belongs in here? I mean, when it comes to other programming languages like Java, I would have no problem creating an ArrayList instead to do the job. I was actually unsure as to how to do this in arduino, hence why I thought about adding this here instead. I wasn't really used to a different language and the low amount of available memory. xD

Comment: Maybe this will be useful for you
http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/QueueArray

Comment: Template Queue class from Cosa; https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Queue.hh used in the Event class https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Event.hh

Comment: Alternatively a double linked cyclic list (queue) with fast insert and remove at any position; https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Linkage.hh used in Job/Scheduler queues; https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Job.hh

Comment: You wrote: “_the problem with array I believe is that it doesn't allow me to shift the data to the left_”. No, that's not the problem: you can shift the data if you wish with [`memmove()`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html#ga8efa99bafd35937d045832774bf57486). The problem is that doing so is inefficient, as you would be copying all the data each time you shift out one element. That's why the answers you got suggest implementing the queues as [circular buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: @Tsubakura: The reason it still belongs in SO rather than here is because what you're asking is a pretty generic question about doing something in C. It's useful to say, when posting problems like this, "I know how to do this in Java" and perhaps even provide a small fragment of Java code so we can see how you're thinking and explain just the stuff you don't understand, rather than the stuff you do.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a simple queue library some weeks ago, you can find it in the arduino library manager, or here:
[Queue](https://github.com/SMFSW/Queue)

I think you need FIFO implementation, but LIFO is also implemented in the lib & possibility to overwrite previous records when full.
It can handle any structure or data type (as long as it's size is fixed for memory allocation), defining a number of records in the queue, then you're good to go.

2 methods are implemented to interact with the queue, push() & pull().
I'll probably add a peek() later on if needed.

I also noticed this other FIFO only queue lib in the library manager when I commited mine: [MD_CirQueue](https://github.com/MajicDesigns/MD_CirQueue)

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding how to “create a queue of some sort for Arduino”, about the first thing to settle is how many items may need to be queued.  On a typical personal computer with gigabytes of RAM, queue size often is not much of an issue ... one just allocates a few more megabytes whenever necessary.  On an typical Arduino, however, with a few kilobytes or few tens of kilobytes of RAM, use of dynamic (heap) allocation is risky unless you carefully analyze possible execution paths.

If you are ok with a fixed queue size, the next issue is what kind of queue, eg FIFO, LIFO, priority, etc.  The question's concern about a “shift the data to the left, so that the next one will be selected in the queue” issue suggests a FIFO (first in first out) queue is desired.  For this, a [circular buffer or circular queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) is a relatively-low-overhead method often used.  Using terms from the wikipedia article, Start and End pointers are maintained, marking next-data-out and last-data-in positions.  Via modular arithmetic or `if` tests, each of these pointers wraps to array front whenever it goes past the array end.   The queue is empty if `Start == End` (modulo N, if queue size is N) and full if `Start == End+1`.

If an interrupt-driven process can modify pointers asynchronously to the main thread of execution, then synchronization methods need to be used to ensure atomic updates of pointers.  (This is true for all kinds of queues, not just circular ones.)

If instead of a FIFO queue you need a priority queue, a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) is easy to implement. Usually [Fibonacci heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) and [binomial heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap) are not worth the extra trouble of implementing, except when you need efficient heap merging or secondary operations like decreasing keys of elements.  The [Summary of running times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap#Summary_of_running_times) section of wikipedia's binomial heap article shows the complexity of different operations across different heap structures.  Note that with Arduino RAM being so limited, a complexity difference like Θ(log n) vs Θ(1) is negligible; simplicity of code, leading to a compact implementation, is more important.

Note, also see [*QueueList Library For Arduino*](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/QueueList) at arduino.cc.  This library apparently uses dynamic allocation.  It provides methods `push(), pop(), peek()` et al.  Also see [*QueueArray Library For Arduino*](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/QueueArray) at arduino.cc, which provides the same methods as *QueueList*, plus `enqueue` and `dequeue()` as synonyms for `push()` and `pop()`.  Where *QueueList* uses lists to build its data structures, *QueueArray* uses arrays.

[*OsWrap* at arduino.cc](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/OsWrap) is a heavy package (eg 15KB flash, 1.5KB RAM) that supports various message and priority queue structures.

Depending on your rationale for using a queue, [*Task Scheduler Library*](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/TaskScheduler) may also be of interest.

As noted in Mikael Patel's comments above, [Cosa](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa) platform software includes a [Queue](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Queue.hh) class, which is a “Template class for ring-buffer for queueing data elements”, with usage of the class illustrated in an [Event](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Event.hh) class, which in turn is used in a [Job](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Job.hh) class.

Answer (score 0):

I had an arduino project that I needed to build a queue for.

You can [download the source code](https://github.com/sdesalas/Arduino-Queue.h/blob/master/Queue.h) and copy into a file called `Queue.h` next to your arduino `project.ino` file.

Here is a simple interactive example (with the Serial monitor) to see how its used, make sure you set the `baud rate` to 115200 and `No new line`.

```
#include "Queue.h":

Queue<char> queue(10);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()) {
    queue.push(Serial.read());
  }

  Serial.print(millis() / 1000);
  Serial.print(": ");
  int count = queue.count();
  if (count > 0) {
    Serial.print("Found ");
    Serial.print(count);
    Serial.print(" items.. '");
    Serial.print(queue.pop());
    Serial.print("' is the oldest. Next is.. '");
    Serial.print(queue.peek());
    Serial.println("'.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Nothing to process..."); 
  }
  delay(2000);
}
```